# Sequences Tending to Infinity Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that $(a_n)$ tends to infinity, and $(b_n)$ is greater than or equal to $-100$ for all $n$ in the naturals.

Is it necessarily true that ($a_n + b_n$) tends to infinity? Prove your answer is correct.

Comment: Well, $a_n + b_n \ge a_n - 100$.  Does $a_n - 100$ tend toward infinity?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the (**a**n) and **b**n. Whilst (**a**n) is a sequence, is **b**n just a single term?

Comment: No, {b_n} is a sequence of terms.  But the are all greater than 100.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given any positive $K$, however large, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $a_n\gt K+100$ whenever $n\gt N$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ and {$b_n$} is such that all $b_n \ge a_n$ then $b_n \rightarrow \infty$.  That's a theorem that you should be familiar with and able to prove.

Each $a_n + b_n \ge a_n - 100$.  So if $a_n - 100 \rightarrow \infty$ then $a_b + b_n \rightarrow \infty$.  So remains to prove $a_n - 100 \rightarrow \infty$.

If $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ then so does $a_n + c$ for any constant c, should also be a theorem you are familiar and able to prove.

$a_n \rightarrow \infty$ means for any M there is an N such that $a_n > M$ for all n > N.  So for any M find the N that would make it true for M - c, that is, such that $a_n > M - c$ for all n >N.  Then $a_n + c > M$ for all n > N.  So $a_n + c \rightarrow \infty$.

We are done.

In summary, $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ so $a_n -100 \rightarrow \infty$ so $a_n + b_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $a_n + b_n \ge a_n - 100$.